# Change django's default admin but without redirecting the models to the default admin

Tags: python, django, admin

I have a custom administrator but when I click on a model it redirects me to the default administrator django, so it would not make sense to do a custom admin, thanks for your collaboration.

This is my custom admin is in myapp / admin.py, in this case **user / admin.py**, I just want the user logged in without super user visualize the administration of their foundation.

```
class AdminFundacion(AdminSite):
        site_header = "Administracion de fundación"    
        def has_permission(self, request):
            if request.user.is_active : 
                if request.user.rol=='1' :
                    self.index_title="Bienvenido a la gestion de "+str(request.user.fundacion)              
                    return request.user.is_active

AdminFundacion = AdminFundacion(name='fundacion-admin')
AdminFundacion.register(Fundacion,FundacionAdmin)
```

This is your respective URL in myapp / url.py

```
from users.admin import AdminFundacion
url(r'^fundacion-admin/$', AdminFundacion.urls),
```

When I register the model in the customized admin (Admin Foundation), without registering the model in the default admin:

```
admin.site.register(Fundacion, FundacionAdmin)
```

This appears to me, as the model is disabled:

When I register the model in the default admin, the model is enabled but when I click on the model, it loses the url **user / fundacion-admin /** or app / fundacion-admin / and redirects it to admin / app or admin / users in this case

What can I do so that I can only manage from the custom admin ?.

Comment: Why are you using a custom admin?

Comment: Because I need something different from the default django administrator, what I did was use django-adminlite and do the cruds manually, it is an alternative but not efficient.

Comment: I developed `django-admin-interface`, maybe you will like it: https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/django-admin-interface